# Strange edges on FAB

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

Strange edges appear when using floatingactionbutton on a device with api 19. When i put the elevation to 0 fixes the edges, but when i press the button the edges appear again. How can i fix this?

[image]

Here my floatingactionbutton :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@mipmap/qrcode"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/primaryColor"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Try setting `app:borderWidth="0dp"`.

Comment: Shows the same thing